# Как скомпилировать python в .exe вместе с изображениями, которые используются в коде?

Tags: python

В коде использую несколько изображений, которые находятся в той же директории, что и сам .py файл. При компиляции через pyinstaller, готовый .exe файл не работает, если в папке с ним нет тех самых изображений. Есть ли какой-то флаг, который добавит нужные мне файлы в исполняемый?

Comment: вы не файлы добавляете, а их отображения в хекс\байт коде, загуглите как сохранить "ссылку" на изображение при работе с pyinstaller